# How To use page.type in google puppeteer correctly

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

[image]

So I'm trying to add a value to simple input box using puppeteer.  The problem is that it will truncate the first letter or first few letters.  To my understanding, the `await page.waitFor` won't result until that selector is visible on the DOM.

```
function test(){
  (async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://sadfasdfasdf.com');
    await page.click('#signup_forms_submit');
    await page.waitFor('#signup_email');
    await page.type('#signup_email','test@gmail.com',{delay: 120});
    console.log('test');
  })();
}
```

Comment: by default it will not truncate the letter, try without delay or post the URL.